# Problem with Two DbSet of two types A and B with B that inherits from A

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6

I have two class Profile and JobProfile, JobProfile inherit from Profile.
I am using Entity Framework 6 and in my dbContext I have two DbSet :

```
public DbSet<JobProfile> JobProfiles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
```

I have also a DAL :

```
public class DAL : IDisposable
{
        BddContext db;
        public DAL()
        {
            db = new BddContext();
        }

        public async Task<ObservableCollection<Profile>> GetProfiles()
        {
            var oc = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
            var profiles = await(db.Profiles
                        .Include("FolderInformationAction")
                        .Include("FolderInformationStore")
                        .ToListAsync());
            foreach (var item in profiles)
            {
                oc.Add(item);
            }
            return oc;
        }

        public async Task<ObservableCollection<JobProfile>> GetJobProfiles()
        {
            var oc = new ObservableCollection<JobProfile>();
            var profiles = await (db.JobProfiles
                        .Include("FolderInformationAction")
                        .Include("FolderInformationStore")
                        .ToListAsync());
            foreach (var item in profiles)
            {
                oc.Add(item);
            }
            return oc;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
}
```

And when I call GetProfiles, it returns Profiles and JobProfiles elements but when I call GetJobProfiles, it returns only JobProfiles elements.

So the question is, how can I make a difference between the two DbSet ? it seems that they are linked.

Comment: What are the columns in the two tables in the database?  What do you mean by differences?

Comment: I use entity framework code first, the generated database has only one table Profiles that store the two DbSet.

Comment: By difference I mean that I want GetProfiles to return only elements in db.Profiles and GetJobProfiles to return only elements in db.JobProfiles

Comment: A dataset consists of one or more datatables.  You cannot have ONE TABLE if you have db.JobProfile (one table) and db.Profiles (another table).

Comment: Well I though like you but it's what I have with this code.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs  Are you using SQL Server as your database (mdf file).  You should be able to view the database structure and verify the number of tables and columns in each table.

Comment: I am using SQL compact CE database and I can see the structure, and as I said there is only one Table that has a column named Discriminator to make the difference between the two type.

Comment: Do you understand everything on following page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: yes I do, I did some explicit loading to solve my problem : .Where( p => !(p is JobProfile)) but I believe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think TPH does that by default.  Use this to trim down or maybe TPT will do what you want by definition.

```
var profiles = await(db.Profiles
    .Where(q => !(q is JobProfile)                        
    .Include("FolderInformationAction")
    .Include("FolderInformationStore")
    .ToListAsync());
```